# Angular - How to take an argument from a function, and use it as a variable name to do something?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a function that will do the following:

I have some text-boxes and each of them is linked to a variable with a name like:

`"textbox1"`, `"textbox2"` and so on.

My function needs to change the value of a `textbox`, when a `(change)` event is triggered.
Depending on where the event happens, I want to change the value of a specific `textbox`.

In words, my function would do this:

```
func foo(newVal: string, textboxNumber: number) {

    this.textbox + textboxNumber = newVal;

}
```

so basically, construct the `textbox` variable name (ie. `textbox1`), and the correct number is passed as argument to the function.
I just don't know how to construct the name of the variable and make it usable!

I know I could for example use CASES, so for each different case, I would use the correct value:

```
SWITCH (myCase) {
    case 1 : this.textbox1 = newVal;
}
```

but the number of `textbox` is dynamic and growing, so I would like a solution like mine, where I decide in the argument of the function which `textbox` is going to get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add dynamic object properties using the bracket syntax instead of dot syntax:

```
function foo(newVal: string, textboxNumber: number) {
  this['textbox' + textboxNumber] = newVal;
}
```

Comment: this is working exactly as I needed! thank you

Comment: what about this, I pass an object as argument to my function, and the object has multiple property like : value1, value2, value3...and so on. 
How can I achieve the same as above for this case? Like:  ArgumentObject.value[currentNumber]   -> where currentNumber will be 1 or 2 or 3 and so on,

Comment: That depends on what you like to achieve. Do you want each array value to create a new sub-property, like `[1, 2, 3]` should become `ArgumentObject.value['1']['2']['3']`?